# How do I know where to add a specific query in php code for adding autocompletion feature with Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

My problem is the following :

I want to add an autocompletion feature for my website generated using Wordpress. I am using a plugin (Armember) for generating signup/contact form, and a basic theme (twenty twenty).

I do not have very much experience in php/Js, so I am very lost when coming to code injection and stuff like that.

**My concern is more about what I can do to trigger an event like 'user is typing' in user_name field and that after 3 inputs, launch query (API, SQL, JQuery etc..) to try to guess what user is trying to input.**

I have already tried many things, but I am very lost with all those files in ***wp-content*** folder.

Comment: You need to narrow the question down to something more specific. You also need to show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. Currently, this question is too unspecific and broad. Try and break the feature into smaller pieces. First do some research about events in javascript (how to detect that someone is typing), then about how to make Ajax requests in JS and WP, Then you research how to make a query for auto completion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use jQuery AJAX. For example, you have a input field with an ID #myInput:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<div id="result"></div>
```

User jQuery keyup() function to detect when user type in, trigger an AJAX call to find in database. Something like this:

```
$("#myInput").keyup(function(event) {
            var getInput = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "handle-form.php",
                method: "GET",
                data: { input: getInput, },
                success: function(res) {
                    $("#result").html(res);
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.log(err);   
                }
            });
        });
```

Then create a PHP file call handle-form.php, inside that you can try to query in your database, using SQL with the keyword LIKE to find values in a specific column that have the same character with what users typed in. Something like this:

```
$input = $_GET['input'];
if ( $input ) {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_column_name LIKE '$input'";
   // after that, make a foreach loop to display what you get.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful, that's what I ended up doing. I am using 'input' event instead of KeyUp but I will definitely look at it.